# R script: Installing packages from offline miniCRAN, still tries to access internet

Tags: r, server, rstudio

I need to install multiple R packages on a server with restricted internet access, i.e all cran repositories are blocked. I created an offline miniCRAN repository which also includes dependencies which made it seem like a perfect fit.

The problem is that it seems like R makes calls with https to the local source folder to fetch it. And that seems to be blocked as well on the server.

How do I prevent the installation from accessing the local packages through http calls?

(This process works on a similar server without the same network restrictions)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The script should look like this:

```
install.packages('yaImpute', 
             repos = paste0("file:///", "C:/Temp/miniCRAN/"),
             type = "source")
```